# Is Bash expanding the "*" character in my python command line parameter?

Tags: python, bash

With the following command in `bash`:

```
python myscript.py filename_pattern*
```

I got two different `sys.argv` in two Linux machines:

- **Machine A**:  `sys.argv[1] = filename_pattern*`
- **Machine B**:  `sys.argv[1] = filename_pattern-2013-06-30`

**Note**: `filename_pattern-2013-06-30` is a file in my current directory.

One of my colleague tell me that's the evil of `bash`. But I check the `bash` in two machines are of the same version, and I checked `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` too.

Can anyone point out how come the two same version `bash` act differently ?

Comment: What is the result of `shopt | grep nullglob` on both machines? See this page for an explanation: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs

Comment: Does the file "filename_pattern-2013-06-30" exist on Machine A?

Comment: nop, thanks for the tip..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because in one of your machine, in the folder, there in no file that could match the pattern. So when this happens, the `*` remains. You can test with one computer, with and without a file match the pattern. There is another reason,  the shell option *nullglob* is disabled. You can read the [GNU bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Why you see the different behavior on the two machines is either down to the files present in the directory on both machines or based on the shell options, as pointed out in the comments.

Either way, the way to avoid the problem is to simply surround the argument in quotes so that Bash treats it literally.

```
python myscript.py "filename_pattern*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle it in your python program like this example that I found in an introductory book on python. Then it won't matter if bash expands it or not.

```
import glob
import sys

sys.argv = [item for arg in sys.argv for item in glob.glob(arg)]
```

Comment: This is a great hack, but it has one little drawback.  In the shell you can use quotes or escape characters if you need to pass a literal `*` in an argument.  This bypasses that.  More seriously, it silently drops any argument that isn't a valid file name.